# Copy website content from WebsiteA.com/file.html to WebsiteB/file.com every time interval

Tags: php, looking-for-a-script, transfer, automation, copy

I want to copy a website from `Website A` to `Website B` every 10 minutes. Then with purple-include I want to do a transclusion and display it on `mywebsite.com/page.html`

So the task is download `websiteA.com/file` to `websiteB.com/file`

I figured out the transclusion part but I do not know how to copy a webpage from A to B. Are there any script for this or how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the file on pingdom is available over HTTP, just read in the page using the server side language of your choice and save it to a file or your database. With PHP you can use [`file_get_contents()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php).

See [this page](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/programming/php-get-the-contents-of-a-web-page-rss-feed-or-xml-file-into-a-string-variable/) for more on this.

Answer (score 0):

You also can use [curl functions](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) for more advanced control of your distant request.